# Вводится произвольное число. набор заканчивается, когда мы вводим 0. Определите, увеличивается ли введенное число

Tags: c#

Есть такое решение но это не правильно.

```
Console.Write("input number:");
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int num);
int max;
int a;
bool b = true;

do
{
    if (num > 10)
    {
        a = num / 10 % 10;
        max = num % 10;
        if (a <= max)
        {
            b = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    num /= 10;
} while (num != 0);

if (b==false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("yes");
}
if (b==true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("no");
}
```

Comment: Какое отношение написанный код имеет к заданию? С тем же успехом можно было чуть ли не произвольный код запостить. Если вы пытаетесь переделать чужой код - то лучше напишите свой, у вас будет намного короче, т.к. тут много лишнего и вообще не относящегося к задаче.

Comment: Никто не пытается забрать чужой код. Я решила с этим кодом и не получилось и на всякий случай я поставила этот код.